# Resources for Teaching High School Statistics

Tags: statistics, education

I am a student teacher looking for resources to teach high school Probability & Statistics (untracked). The second semester will be inferential statistics and will include these following topics:

(1) Normal Distribution (2) z-Scores (3) Central Limit Theorem (4) Sampling Distributions (5) Confidence Interval (6) Margin of Error (7) Hypothesis Testing, including one tailed and two tailed tests (8) t-Scores and (9) Chi-Square Distribution

I would like to know what kind of resources are there available for me to do an effective presentation while also incorporating the nationwide Common Core standards. Obviously, I cannot teach this class like a lectured-based college class. This class has to be student-oriented as in filled with activities and different checking points to assess their understanding. The challenge I feel is making this material accessible to all students. The minimum prerequisite to take this class is a C in Algebra II though there are a few who have taken AP Calculus AB along with the untracked Pre-Calculus and H Precalculus with at least a D.

My big question is, should I teach this class based on a conceptual understanding of the terminology involved, its procedures and applications while ignoring the mathematical derivations? For example, if I were to talk to about the binomial distribution should I deliberately ignore discussing deriving the mean and variance? Is it wise for me to not even mention what a moment generating function is?

Comment: Wise not to mention a moment generating function? In high school? Definitely yes!

Comment: I fail to see why it is obvious that you cannot teach this class like a lecture-based college class... ;) /tongue-in-cheek  Seriously, though, I am curious as to why this is the case.

Comment: Jealous of your students!